# Incorrect scale when importing .Obj files

Tags: objects, export, import

IM trying to import a character created in 3ds Max.
It has 7 cm in Max, but when it is imported into Blender it interprets it as a  700 cm model.

How does Blender handle scale?

Comment: Hello :). What format do you use for export from Max?

Comment: Hello,

Im exporting in obj

Comment: I'm facing same problem with obj then I tried with fbx. Export as fbx in 3ds Max. FBX will export the actual dimensions of the 3DS Max into Blender.

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistent scale is a common annoyance when using different software.
Fortunately, you can clamp the size during import.

*Clamp the imported file to a fixed size.*

[image]

*To illustrate different clamp results*

[image]